# Radiated power of a dipole in a medium

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, greens-functions, dipole, classical-field-theory

I would like to calculate the power of an electric radiating dipole inside a medium with $\varepsilon$ and $\mu$ and compare it to the power of a free dipole in vacuum. How do I go about it?

My idea is to use the Green's function inside a medium to find the electric field first and to square it then ($|\vec{E}|$).

$$\vec{E} = G_{\varepsilon, \mu} \vec p$$

What is the expression for $G_{\varepsilon, \mu}$ that should be used here? In vacuum it has a dependence on $\frac{e^{ikr}}{4 \pi r}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without getting into too much detail, I would do it this way. I would replace the light speed $c$ in the [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Dipole_radiation) of dipole radiation in vacuum with the light speed in medium,
$$c^{\prime}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon \mu}}.$$.